# How to get a JavaScript script to stay within its designated element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pretty much what it says on the tin.

I have a JS script that isn't staying within the div element it is designated to on my page, it "sits" in the footer section instead.
[Page design with the JS script result "sitting" in the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dpil.png)

```
<header>

    <div>icon</div>
    <div>header</div>
    <div style="padding:5px;">
    script is supposed to go here
        <script src="JS/SpinningBaton.js"></script>
    </div>
  
</header>
```

That's how I currently have the HTML block written in an attempt to resolve the issue. Unfortunately, nothing has changed. What am I doing to wrong?

For context, the div element is 165px in size while the JS script is 155px, so it should fit without overflow.

I have tried putting the script within different elements within the div and resizing the div element. But the script defiantly stays in the footer area regardless of what I have tried so far.

SpinningBaton code, as requested - I'd include the code that makes the script actually work, but it exceeds the limit:

```js
angleMode = "radians";

var angle = 0;
var aVelocity = 0;
var aAcceleration = 0.0001;
// var TargetSpeed = ((Math.random() * 2)-1)/2;

function RandNum(){
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return a;
}

Num1 = RandNum();
Num2 = RandNum();
Num3 = RandNum();
Num4 = RandNum();
Num5 = RandNum();
Num6 = RandNum();
Num7 = RandNum();
Num8 = RandNum();
Num9 = RandNum();
Num10 = RandNum();
Num11 = RandNum();
Num12 = RandNum();

draw = function() {
    createCanvas(155,155);
    
    resetMatrix();
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    rotate(angle);
    
    stroke(0, 0, 0,0);
    fill(Num1, Num2, Num3);
    
    ellipse(60, 0, 32, 32);
    fill(Num4, Num5, Num6);
    ellipse(-60, 0, 32, 32);
    fill(Num7, Num8, Num9);
    ellipse(0, 60, 32, 32);
    fill(Num10, Num11, Num12);
    ellipse(-0, -60, 32, 32);
    
    if (aVelocity < TargetSpeed)
    {
        aVelocity += aAcceleration;
    }
    else
    {
        aVelocity -= aAcceleration;
    }
    angle += aVelocity;
};
```

Comment: Where the dynamically created element will be placed is determined by JavaScript code not the location of the `<script>` tag. Show us your JS/SpinningBaton.js file contents

Comment: Elements can be created in HTML source, by using `document.createElement`, by creating HTML source to add to an existing element's `innerHTML` property, or by  `document.write` calls during page load (not recommended). Where the canvas appears on the page depends on correct identification of its parent element in script and/or any [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) applied to the element in CSS. Could you edit the question to include the nature of what `createCanvas` produces and how the canvas is actually added to the document please?

Answer (score 0):

1. grab that div element using the the id or class
2. then in js file render the result in that element

refer:- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dom-document-object-model/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

I don't think JavaScript works like that. A JavaScript script doesn't work when you place it in some kind of object (div in this case). Instead it is always supposed to be put at the end of the HTML page (before the body ending tag usually) and it works accordingly what you have written inside it.

Here you are considering JavaScript as a HTML object (just live divs, paragraphs, header tags etc.) but it isn't like that.

Comment: I down voted this answer because it says " javascript script doesn't work when you place it in some kind of object (div in this case) **instead it is always supposed to be** put at the end of the HTML page".